# jQuery forced "float:left" during animation of show("blind") method

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am creating an alert box for a web form, when an input error is detected jQuery will be used to show this error message to the user.

The div is styled as follow in css: `width:60%; margin: 0 auto;`

However when I call `$("#aDivId").show("blind");` I noticed something akward. **During** the animation, the div was temporarily assigned a css property of "float:left" so the div will no longer be centered, once the animation completes, it kind of "reloads" the css and re-positioned it correctly at the center.

This makes the div appears at the left, animated, then jumped to the center.

Has anyone been in the same situation please?

Comment: you could use firebug to see where that `float:left` is coming from.

Comment: Perhaps post a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) demonstrating the issue? I checked the example on jQuery UI docs and couldn't see the `float: left` property being assigned.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? What I discovered playing on jsFiddle is that this only happens on Firefox, not Chrome. Here is my test: http://jsfiddle.net/WRNRV/5/

Comment: @HenriqueAbreu Yes, this is actually a known issue in the current release of jQuery (back in March) and they have documented it. It was fixed in the pre-release version. That was in March and I cannot remember the version number where it got fixed. Basically try the current version, if it still fails go ahead and download the developing version and that should solve it. Cheers